# Cannot Remote Desktop into Windows 2016 server after adding many Windows users

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

Hoping you can help. I am running a brand new Windows 2016 server image on AWS EC2.

I run a bat file which adds about 2000 sites into IIS (using appcmd.exe) an equal amount of FTP virtual directories and a windows user (netuser.exe) for each one. Everything is works fine, however when I log off the server and try to reconnect with Remote Desktop, I get a blue screen now that says, "Please wait for local session manager", but the connection always time's out and eventually closes.

I have done this two times on two brand new instances with new images. In other words, I can replicate this issue with different hardware. The second instance was a much more powerful one, so it's not RAM related as with some of the articles I've read while trying to see what could be the problem.

The server is still responsive. I can see websites it runs and I am also in the middle of copying files to it from another server which I can is still working.

I have tried rebooting, and stopping and then starting my instance.

Does anyone have any ideas how I may gain access to the server again? Since this is AWS I can't call anyone :/

I have tried RDPing with /admin flag but that still does not help.

I have tried RDPing from another IP and Machine and still no love.

This server is not in an AD.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would seem that there is actually no problem at all. Just that Remote Desktop was timing out before the Local Session Manager had completed.

To keep the connection open, I just kept clicking on the center of the window every 10 seconds or so (very high tech solution).